# next js 14 with mysql authentication res.status is not a function

Tags: authentication, next.js

I am trying to make authentication next js 14 with mysql when i try to register a user this error appears "TypeError: res.status is not a function".

I didnt know why and solutions?

api/register:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "@/utils/db";

export async function POST(req, res) {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;

  const db = await connectToDatabase();

  const existingUser = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [
    email,
  ]);

  if (existingUser.length > 0) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email already registered" });
  }

  await db.query(
    "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
    [username, email, password]
  );

  res.status(200).json({ message: "Registration successful" });
}
```

registerform:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/register", formData);
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error registering user:", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: What does this error have to do with MySQL? It seems to be an issue with how you're calling the `POST()` function. What is the value of `res`?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: You're trying to call `res.status()`. The error says that it's not a function. So the issue is with `res`, not the database query.

Comment: any idea what should i do? ps: i added how im calling the function

Comment: I gave you a link to a similar question that shows how to resolve this error.